# Android parent onTouchEvent hijacking child onTouchEvent

Tags: android, imageview, android-scrollview

I have an android application screen in which I have a form where user can take image and fill details about the pic. I also want user to write something over the image (its like drawing with your finger), but the problem is that too many fields have made the view scrollable and therefore user is not able to draw over the image. Can I somehow disable the parent scrolling when I am touching my imageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with :

```
mYourImageView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

Called when a child does not want this parent and its ancestors to intercept touch events with onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent).

Comment: ImageView does not have method requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent

Comment: Your right, how about you put your ImageView inside a layout and use requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); on that layout?